# How to create a date input field with a value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using this example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-5kz7gt

I'm creating a form dynamically like this.

I also added a date field which looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "date",
  template: `

    <input
         *ngIf="!field.multiline"
         [attr.type]="field.type"
         class="form-control"
         [id]="field.name"
         [name]="field.name"
         [formControl]="form"
       />

      <textarea
        *ngIf="field.multiline"
        [class.is-invalid]="isDirty && !isValid"
        [formControlName]="field.name"
        [id]="field.name"
        rows="9"
        class="form-control"
        [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
      ></textarea>

  ,
})
export class DateComponent {
  @Input() field: any = {};
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  get isValid() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].valid;
  }
  get isDirty() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].dirty;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

Setting a value inside here however, will not be displayed inside the input field

```
{
      type: 'date',
      name: 'email',
      label: 'Email',
      value: '08.10.2020',
      required: true,
}
```

The output is always like the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDj7J.png)

As you can see below I've tried to add a date object but it still doesn't display a date.

```
export class DynamicFormBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() fields: any[] = [];
  date = new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required);
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(public router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  let monthAgo = new Date();
    let fieldsCtrls = {};
    for (let f of this.fields) {
      if (f.type != "checkbox" && f.type != "date" ) {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(
          f.value || "",
          Validators.required
        );
      } else if (f.type != "checkbox" && f.type == "date" )
      {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(
                new Date(),
                Validators.required
              );
              console.log("I'm inside date");

      }
       else {
        let opts = {};
        for (let opt of f.options) {
          opts[opt.key] = new FormControl(opt.value);
        }
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormGroup(opts);
      }
    }
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup(fieldsCtrls);
  }

    close() {
        this.router.navigate(["partners/partner-list"]);
    }


}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is that second code block (where `type: 'text', (...)`)? Is it what you pass to child component?

Comment: type is date i edited it, accidently wrote text. Yes this is what you pass to the child object. It's quite huge to write the whole concept so please have a look at the stackblitz :). I have tried adding a date object but it still does not display the date. I tried it now like this:                              `fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl (new Date('2020-10-08'), Validators.required);`

Comment: you need give the value in format yyyy-mm-dd NOTE: I remove my before comment -use new Date(..) because I just check and NOT work- the stackblitz your show updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-5kz7gt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Ahhh this was the format, thank you very much :)